# Software (preferable Excel add-in or similar) to abbreviate large number of sentences based on user-set database

Tags: microsoft-excel

We have to take a large number of rows, each containing a text sentence. We need to abbreviate each sentence to have a character length of < 40, as we need to copy-paste the data to SAP which has this limitation (a long-text option is available in SAP, but requires manual fill-in, which we are trying to avoid).

I was wondering if there is a software/Excel add-in/macro that abbreviates sentences based on a database/dictionary that is set by the user.

E.g. My data base contents could look like:

1. Character -> Char
2. Management -> Mgnt
3. Time -> t

Based on this, when I run the program, the sentence "Character Building and Time Management" becomes "Char Building and t Mgnt".

Comment: When and how should the tool interact with the data? As far as I understand your description, the tool loads an existing Excel file, replaces some strings based on a database and then saves the file again. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

This could be accomplished very easily with Excel VBA.

```
Sub FindandReplace()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim InputRng As Range, ReplaceRng As Range
    xTitleId = "FindandReplace"

    Set InputRng = Application.Selection
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range to Replace", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set ReplaceRng = Application.InputBox("Lookup Range :", xTitleId, Type:=8)

    For Each Rng In ReplaceRng.Columns(1).Cells
        InputRng.Replace what:=Rng.Value, replacement:=Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Next
End Sub
```

Steps on how to install the code.

1. Hold down **ALT + F11** to view Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications window. (pictured below)
2. Click **Insert > Module**
3. Paste above code into newly opened window.

[image]

4. Save the file as an *.xlsm extension.  E.g. book1.xlsm
5. Create the range of cells that will be modified.

[image]

6. Create the range of cells with the replacement rules.

[image]

7. Steps on how to use the code from Excel

   - In Excel: Hold down **Alt + F8**
   - Select "FindandReplace" from the list
   - Click "Run"

[image]

8. Highlight the range you would like to modify
9. Highlight the replacement rules.
10. End Result (below)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Essential XlsIO](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/xlsio) allows for reading and writing Excel files programmatically and has an [API for replacing text](http://help.syncfusion.com/ug/windows%20forms/index.html#!Documents/findandreplace3.htm).

This could be an option for you if you are willing to use the API and replace text based on your database/dictionary.

The entire product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify.

-Davis(Syncfusion)